# How do I add an index page to the GitLab bundled NGINX?

Tags: linux, centos, nginx, centos-7, gitlab

I've recently installed GitLab, and I'm using the bundled NGINX with it. I've been able to successfully set it up, and put it on mydomain.com/lab

Great! Only problem is that when you go to mydomain.com, it has a 404 page. Well, duh. I need to upload my index.html... but WHERE do I do it? How can I add my index page to the bundled NGINX? Most of all, WHERE do I upload it?

I'm using CentOS 7, and for the love of God I swear I've looked in every directory and I have no idea where to throw my index page in. Please bear with my ignorance as I'm quite new to this.

Thanks,
Joel.

Comment: Where did you get gitlab from? Did you fork it from **github** repository?

Comment: @sajinmp I used the Omnibus package, as told to do in this tutorial: https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#centos7

Comment: Oh. I haven't tried that @miles. Sorry. I'll try that over the weekend.